# Routing error in Rails embedded form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have embedded a rails form as a simple dropdown menu in an html table. I have also implemented the form in such a way that whenever there is a change in the drop down menu then the form is submitted. But I am getting a routing error which I am trying to resolve.

### The form code:

```
 <td>
            <%= form_for(lead, :action => 'update_lead_status', :html => {:id => 'lead_form'}, :remote => true) do |f| %>
                <%= f.select(:status, ["to_call","called","confirmed","lite"], {:selected => lead.status}, :onchange => "$('#lead_form').submit();") %>
            <% end %>
    </td>
```

### The routes.rb file:

```
get 'leads/:id/edit_lead_status' => "leads#edit_lead_status"
  put 'leads/:id/update_lead_status'=> "leads#update_lead_status"
```

### The leads_controller.rb file:

```
#PUT
  def update_lead_status
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      if @lead.update_attributes(params[:lead])
        format.html { redirect_to leads_url, notice: 'Lead was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Also my embedded form in the table is at the /leads URL where I try to redirect on successful update.

### The logs from my server:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/leads/130"):
```

status is an accessible attribute in my leads model.

Please let me know where I am going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

So I tried sevenseacat's answer and it called my update_lead_status but with a wrong parameter. My table is like this:

```
<% @leads.each do |lead| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= lead.id %></td>
    <td><%= lead.prefix %></td>
    <td><%= lead.name %></td>
    <td><%= lead.mobile %></td>
    <td><%= lead.phone %></td>
    <td><%= lead.category %></td>
    <td><%= lead.area %></td>
    <td><%= lead.city %></td>
    <td><%= lead.updated_at %></td>
    <td><%= lead.is_valid %></td>
    <td><%= lead.vendor_status %></td>
    <td><%= lead.call_tries %></td>
    <td>
        <%= form_for(lead, url: update_lead_status_path(lead.id), :html => {:id => 'lead_form'}, :remote => true) do |f| %>
            <%= f.select(:status, ["to_call","called","confirmed","lite"], {:selected => lead.status}, :onchange => "$('#lead_form').submit();") %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= lead.remarks %><%= link_to lead.remarks, :controller => "leads", :action => "edit_lead_remarks", :id => lead, :remote => true %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Here for every row in the table it takes id as the id of the first lead in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying the action URL for the form properly - it should be for example `form_for(lead, url: update_lead_status_path(lead))`

(assuming you have [named your route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) in your routes.rb, eg, `as: :update_lead_status`).

Comment: This did work in the sense that my update_lead_status function is being called. However, the lead.id which is being passed is always the id of the first lead in the table. See update...

Comment: Do not use `lead.id` - my code example was `update_lead_status_path(lead)`.

Comment: There was an error in my html. In the sense I was naming every row's form as form_html and when I set id as form_html it called the form for the latest lead and not the specific lead.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, thanks a lot.. had spent 3 hours throwing things around. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding following line of code in your routes.rb file.

```
resources :leads
```